# Yii2 Delete Alert box not working

Tags: php, yii2

I generated a model,controller and a view by Gii,And I enabled the actionColumn in  index.php.
I have delete button to delete the records.The buttons are working good but,It doesn't shows me the Alert box to confirm my action.
I am attaching my code here.
Can anyone tell what  I am missing?
**Index.php**

```
    <?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\grid\GridView;


$this->title = 'Cities';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = '/ '.$this->title;
?>
<div class="cities-index">

    <h2><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?>
    <?php //echo $this->render('_search', ['model' => $searchModel]); ?>

        <?= Html::a('Create Cities', ['create'], ['class' => 'btn btn-success','style'=>'float:right']) ?>

</h2>
    <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        //'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

            // 'country_id',
            [
             'attribute'=>'country_id',
             'value'=>'country.country_name',
            ],
            'city_name',
            'city_tax',

            [   'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
                'header'=>'Action',
                'template'=>'{view}{update}{delete}',
                'buttons' => [
                    'view' => function ($url, $model) {
                        return Html::a('<span  class="btn btn-xs btn-success  icon-search bigger-120" style="margin-left:5px;"></span>', $url, [
                                    'title' => Yii::t('app', 'View'),
                        ]);
                    },
                    'update' => function ($url, $model) {
                        return Html::a('<span class="btn btn-xs btn-info icon-pencil blue bigger-120" style="margin-left: 5px;"></span>', $url, [
                                    'title' => Yii::t('app', 'Update'),'<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>'
                        ]);
                    },
                    'delete' => function ($url, $model) {
                        return Html::a('<span class="btn btn-xs btn-danger icon-trash  bigger-120" style="margin-left: 5px;" ></span>', 
                            $url, [
                                    'title' => Yii::t('app', 'Remove'),'<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>',
                                    'data-confirm' => 'Are You sure',
                                    'data-method' => 'post'
                        ]);
                    },                                    
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ]); ?>

</div>
```

Comment: working for me. seems like you were missing something.

Comment: Can I share my Controller??I don't know what I'm missing....

Comment: Is yii.js loaded into the browser?

Comment: I have already tested your code, working perfectly. Check your script loaded or not in browser console.